# Можно ли соеденить входные данные от flag.Arg

Tags: golang

Коротко.
Входные данные:

1. one two three
2. one two

Выход:.
1 * one two * tree
2 * one * two

Если значений меньше чем 3, то нужно выводить как в примере 2.
Если 3, то пример 1
Всё бы ничего, нужно решить без всякой сложности (нельзя использовать if/else).

Что не так?..

```
func main(){
    flag.Parse()
    pulse := flag.Arg(0) + " " + flag.Arg(1)
    fmt.Println("*"+pulse+"*", flag.Arg(2)
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать в сообщество.  (1) Не открывайте вопросы про одно и то же.  (2) Добавляйте **рабочий** код, а не обрезанный, как у вас в вопросах.  (3) Описывайте задачу подробно.  (С каких пор простые операторы ветвления стали «сложностью»?)

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
    one := flag.String("one", "", "one")
    two := flag.String("two", "", "two")
    three := flag.String("three", "", "three")
    flag.Parse()
    pulse := *one + " " + *two
    fmt.Println("*"+pulse+"*", *three)
}
```